# Does this data set contradict the assumption of the physical model?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

In a problem physical model suggests that increase in temperature should not exceed 5 C. So, 8 independent measurements are recorded.

$6.4 ,4.3 ,5.7, 4.9, 6.5, 5.9, 6.4, 5.1$ (sample) and $\alpha = 0.05$.

Does this data set contradict the assumption of the physical model?

I did the following:

Since we need Hypothesis testing then $H_0: \mu\le 5$ (Claim) and $H_a:\mu\ge 5$ then mean $= 5.65$ with $s = 0.81.$

Is it the correct way of solving it? Should I continue with finding critical value?

Comment: Learn some basic [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math and try to ask the actual question in the [title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/321264).

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks sensei

Comment: You have to take into consideration how measurement errors (if any) are incorporated into assessing the physical model.  And why do think this is a test about the mean?  Is this about an "average increase in temperature not exceeding 5 C" or "any increase of temperature not exceeding 5 C" ?

Answer (score 1):

## One-sample t test of $H_0: \mu \le 5$ against $H_a: \mu > 5.$

[Notice that alternative hypothesis should have $>,$ *not* $\ge.]$

Your data are as follows (entered into R statistical software):

```
x = c(6.4, 4.3, 5.7, 4.9, 6.5, 5.9, 6.4, 5.1)
mean(x);  sd(x)
[1] 5.65
[1] 0.8106435
```

Here is a stripchart (dotplot) of your data. The vertical line is
located at $\bar X.$

[image]

So, $\bar X = 5.65$ and $S = 0.8106$ are the sample mean and
standard deviation. You should verify this by using the formulas.

Because the sample mean $\bar X > 5$ you may wonder if the
population mean $\mu$ is also greater than $5.$ The question is
whether $5.65$ is *enough* greater than $5$ to be called 'significantly'
greater at the 5% level, and thus reject $H_0.$

Here are results from the required t test computed using R:

```
t.test(x, mu=5, alte="greater")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 2.2679, df = 7, p-value = 0.02883
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 5
95 percent confidence interval:
 5.107003      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
     5.65
```

The first thing you should do is to compute the t statistic
$T = \frac{\bar X - 5}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ to see if you get $T = 2.2679$
as in the printout.

I don't know for sure whether (according to your textbook or class notes) you are supposed to look at
the P-value or the critical value to decide whether to reject
the null hypothesis. [I see you mention 'critical value' in your Question.]

- The **P-value** is based on the assumption that the null hypothesis
  is true. In that case $T$ is distributed according to Student's
  t distribution with degrees of freedom DF $= n - 1 = 7.$ The
  probability $P(T \ge 2.2679)$ is the probability of getting
  a more extreme result (in a positive direction) than the observed
  value 2.2679 is called the P-value. The output tells you
  that the P-value is 0.02883. If the P-value is **smaller** than 0.05 = 5%,
  then you reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level. (Generally speaking you can't determine the exact P-value by looking at a printed table of t distributions. P-values are 'creatures' of the computer age.)
- You can find the **critical value** $c = 1.895$ (to some number of decimal places) by looking a printed t table. Look in the row for DF = 7 and
  in the column for values that cut probability 0.05 from the upper tail
  of the distribution. If the t statistic is **greater** than $c = 1.895,$ then you reject the null hypothesis. Because you have $T = 2.2679,$ you do reject.

The figure below shows the density function of Student's t distribution with DF = 7.

- The heavy black vertical line is at $T = 2.2679.$ The area under
  the curve to the right of this line represents the P-value.
- The dotted red vertical line is at $c =1.895.$ You reject the null hypothesis because the black line is to the right of the red line. This is a 5% critical value; the area under the curve to the right of the dotted red line is 5%.

.
[image]

Comment: How do you justify normality of the given data?